# How to check if input is a number

Tags: c

Im trying to check if the input is a number and if not its going to say that the input is wrong.

```
int menu() 
{
    int menyval;
    printf(" 1. Quit\n 2. Add question \n 3. Competitve \n 4. Show all questions\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &menyval);
    if (isdigit(menyval)==0)
    {
        system("cls");
        return menyval;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("That's not a number!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the result of `scanf_s()`

```
int menu() 
{
    int menyval;
    printf(" 1. Quit\n 2. Add question \n 3. Competitive \n 4. Show all questions\n");
    if (1 == scanf_s("%d", &menyval)) {
        system("cls");
        return menyval;
    }
    else {
        printf("That's not a number!");
    }
}
```

`scanf_s("%d",...)` will return 0,1, (the count of successfully scanned fields) or EOF

```
1: A number was scanned.  
0: Nothing saved `&menyval`, input is not a character representation of a number 
   User input remains in `stdin`.  
EOF:  End-of-file (or input error occurred).
```

Comment: Now I have another intressting question.. The first thing i enter it just ignors it...

Comment: For some reason i need to enter two times before it take my input, any ideas? @Henrik

Comment: @Petrus Lindblom please detail the key sequenced used when you say "enter two times".

Comment: When i run the code for my switch case and im about to enter a number or now also letters I need to enter a letter or a number two times before it actually happends something... im so confused about it

Comment: @Petrus Lindblom  There is no "switch case" in this post.  It appears you are asking about some other code.  Remember 1) that `stdin` is typically "line buffered".  That means `scanf_s()` will not see any input until a `'\n'` occurs. 2) If a letter is entered with `scanf_s("%d"...`, the function returns 0 and the input remains in `stdin`.

Comment: @Petrus Lindblom There are many approaches.  A robust approach is to read user input with `fgets()` and then use `sprintf()`, `strtol()`, etc to parse the buffer read.

Comment: lol! added fflush(stdin) before the scanf_S and problem solved. thank you!

Comment: the statement: fflush(stdin) is, per the standard, undefined behaviour.  so do not use it.  Most compilers will flag it as an error.

Comment: suggest put the prompt/input in a loop, that exits when a valid number (1..4) has been entered

Answer (score 2):

scanf_s, like scanf is supposed to return the number of fields successfully converted and assigned. So look at the return value of scanf_s instead of calling isdigit.

isdigit checks if its argument is between '0' and '9', that is between 0x30 and 0x39 (48-57). Your integer menyval will at success probably be between 1 and 4 so isdigit will fail as isdigit is really intended for chars instead of integers.